# Firebase Automatic Redirect Depending on Users Language

Tags: html, firebase, web, firebase-hosting

I'm a noob trying to do my first html page using Google Firebase Hosting. I created my project with just an index.html and is currently deployed on my domain. I would like to provide 2 different pages on my site, one in english when the user is using their browsers on that language, and in any other case showing the page in spanish.

I've seen a couple questions on how to do this with .htaccess on wordpress, but it appears that this doesn't work on Firebase.

Any suggestions on what can I do or where should I look? I haven't find anything yet on the firebase doccumentation.
Thank's :) sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing URL rewrites based on the browser language was added to Firebase Hosting a few months ago. With these rewrites you can serve different pages, or even completely different set of content, to users based on the `Accept-Language` header that their browser sends. Have a look at the documentation on [configuring i18n rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/i18n-rewrites) for full details.